# Different ouput in similar code - Webscraping with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

In [this](http://www.admision.unmsm.edu.pe/admisionsabado/A/011/0.html) link, I try to count all the numbers that appear as links above the table of the webpage. Check the link to have a better idea. I have two codes that are very similar, but just the first code gives the expected output. So, what is wrong with my second code?

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.admision.unmsm.edu.pe/admisionsabado/A/011/0.html"))
c=[]
for n in soup.find_all('center'):
    for b in n.find_all('a')[1:]:
        c.append(b.text)

t = len(c) / 2

print t
```

The result is 41. In the webpage there 41 numbers which appear as links above the table of the webpage, so the output is right.

In the wrong code, I define a function which its input is a subset of the url. The code is below:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def record(part):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.admision.unmsm.edu.pe/admisionsabado".format(part)))
    c=[]
    for n in soup.find_all('center'):
        for b in n.find_all('a')[1:]:
            c.append(b.text)

    t = len(c)/2
    print t
```

As you see the method for counting the numbers are the same. So, I run the function:

```
record('/A/011/0.html')
```

Unfortunately, the output is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the function, you are formatting the URL string with the passed in parameter, but the format string didn't have the placeholder `{}` in it to place the value at. Here it is with it.

`"http://www.admision.unmsm.edu.pe/admisionsabado{}".format(part)`

Comment: Thanks so much. I didn’t realice that abscense!